# C# .net gridview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridView with a `select` field for each row. When I select the first row I want to be redirected to gamers.aspx page but when I select the second row I want to be sent to the audio.aspx page.

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
Response.Redirect("gamers.aspx? EntityID=" + row.Cells[1].Text);

GridViewRow row1 = GridView1.SelectedRow;
Response.Redirect("audio.aspx? EntityID=" + row.Cells[2].Text);
```

This is what I did but when I click `select` from any of the rows in my gridView it sends me to the gamers.aspx every time.

Comment: Because that's what you told it to do.  Nothing executes after the second line in your code above.

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you suggest anything in order to make this work?

Comment: Look at the answers and check the right one to close this question.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use a switch if i correctly understand your intent.

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
string entityID = row.Cells[1].Text;

switch (row.RowIndex)
{
    case 1:
        Response.Redirect("gamers.aspx?EntityID=" + entityID);
        break;
    case 2:
        Response.Redirect("audio.aspx?EntityID=" + entityID);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect() throws an exception and almost immediately terminates current request. So next code does not get executed.

You probably should check what row was selected and execute the first redirect or the second.

Comment: This is what I have : http://tinypic.com/r/29qi7w1/4  when I select the second row or the third row it takes me to gamers.aspx to be honest Im not sure. I have a unique Identifier which is the ID and I am doing the row.cells[1] in pertinence to that